# Display Date (not time) from Firestore Timestamp

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pulling a timestamp from a Firestore database, and I only want to display the date to the user. The original timestamp is

```
Timestamp(seconds=1555477200, nanoseconds=0)
```

I've tried a few variations to get the Date, but they all have the same output-

> Due: Wed Apr 17 2019 06:10:21 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

```
<p>Due: ${Date(dueDate)}<br>
<p>Due: <time>${Date(dueDate)}</time><br>
<p>Due: <time type="date">${Date(dueDate)}</time><br>
```

How do I cut off the time part of the timestamp?
(Ideally, I'd want "April 17, 2019", but if the day is in there that's fine too)

Comment: please post your time stamp

Comment: What kind of templating language is that supposed to be in the first place?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34015511/5734311

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Posted my timestamp. I think the reason it's not a dup of how to format a JavaScript Date is because it's not in DateTime format (Which is odd, because when I use the same database on mobile, the default is that it pulls in DateTime format)

Comment: there is no way to convert seconds into date :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
var time= timeStampFromFirestore.toDate(); 
console.log(time); 
console.log(time.toDateString());
```

See the full documentation :

[toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString)

[toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.TimeStamp#todate)

Comment: My date isn't in the DateTime format. It's in seconds from epoch. Is there a way to convert it so I can use this (I get 'invalid date' int he console)

Comment: @Caponigri If your variable is a TimeStamp from firestore, you can use firestoreTimestamp.toDate().

Comment: @Caponigri `.toDate()` only return javaScript Date object, you must use `Date.toLocaleString()` to get the desired format like `"April 17, 2019"`

Comment: I think that his question was about how to have a JavaScript Date Object from firestore TimeStamp actually.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a particular format for date, you can do

```
function getDate (timestamp=Date.now()) {
    const date = new Date(timestamp);
    let dd = date.getDate();
    let mm = date.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    const yyyy = date.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd = '0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm = '0'+mm
    } 
    // Use any date format you like, I have used YYYY-MM-DD
    return `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;
}
getDate(1555477200000);
// -> 2019-04-17
```

Alternatively, you can also do:

```
const time = new Date(1555477200000); 
// ->  Wed Apr 17 2019 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
const date = time.toDateString();
// -> Wed Apr 17 2019
```

P.S: I have used ES6 here. If you are working on ES5, use babel's online transpiler to convert.

Link: https://babeljs.io/repl

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Date.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) like this:

```
new Date(date).toLocaleString('en-EN', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
```

```js
const timestamp = 1555477200000;
console.log(
   new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString('en-EN', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and use your required format

```js
date = moment();
console.log(date.format("MMMM D, YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```